# How to translate "Tote Chaser" trully? "азартный преследователь"

Tags: перевод

source: http://leaksource.wordpress.com/2013/12/30/nsas-ant-division-catalog-of-exploits-for-nearly-every-major-software-hardware-firmware/

I think that

tote chaser - азартный преследователь

Am I right?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Most of top-secret codenames are randomly generated pairs of two nouns. Only a few such combinations would be translatable. They are designed not to refer to the purpose of the program/tool nor to have any meaning at all.

Comment: They may not be so random in all cases. In the quoted article, for example, all Juniper implant names end in "TROUGH", while Huawei implants contain "WATER". However I agree, product code names, esp. of this nature, are rarely translated.